# Amazon SPAPI error "could match input arguments"

Tags: sandbox, amazon-selling-partner-api

When I run this SPAPI model I get the error - [SPAPI error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1urrD.png)

My model is -

```
{
"clientReferenceId": "911-xxxxxx-xxxxxx",
"shipFrom": {
    "name": "test name 1",
    "addressLine1": "some Test address 1",
    "postalCode": "90013",
    "city": "Los Angeles",
    "countryCode": "US",
    "stateOrRegion": "CA",
    "email": "testEmail1@amazon.com",
    "phoneNumber": "1234567890"
},
"shipTo": {
    "name": "test name 2",
    "addressLine1": "some Test address 2",
    "postalCode": "90013-1805",
    "city": "LOS ANGELES",
    "countryCode": "US",
    "stateOrRegion": "CA",
    "email": "testEmail2@amazon.com",
    "phoneNumber": "1234567890"
},
"containers": [
    {
        "dimensions": {
            "height": 12,
            "length": 36,
            "width": 15,
            "unit": "CM"
        },
        "weight": {
            "unit": "lb",
            "value": 0.08164656
        }
    }
]
}
```

I want to create an endpoint in amazon spapi in sandbox environment. I get error message - could not match input arguments